# Dynamic IP .htaccess blocklist?

Tags: apache, ip, blacklist

Is it possible to block users from IP adresses with a dynamic file-based blocklist?

So, suppose the .htaccess looks like:

```
order Deny,Allow
Deny from 123.156.0.1
Deny from 10.0.0.10
Allow from all
```

Can this list be made dynamic, for example:

```
order Deny,Allow
[include Deny list here]
Allow from all
```

Another option would of course be to fix it with PHP, but it is preferable to let Apache handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html), it doesn't seem to be possible to read values from a text file.

However, you could [`include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include) a configuration file containing the IP addresses. They would have to be in Apache's conf file format, though.

This should work:

```
order Deny,Allow
include conf/IPList.conf
Allow from all
```

It's even possible to `include` whole directories, even though it's not recommended.

Comment: You have not included the data sample format that should be in in `conf/IPList.conf`, as this is also compulsory part of your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I use the [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) feature from Apache's RewriteModule, as a whitelist like this:

```
## WHITELIST IPS ##
RewriteMap ipslist txt:/path/to/whitelist.txt
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${ipslist:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

With some tweaking, you could make this a blacklist.

Comment: RewriteMap is a nice approach, but will only work in a server or virtual host context, i.e. not .htaccess

Comment: You have not mentioned the location of this script, where this script can be added and what will be data format in `whitelist.txt` or `blacklist.txt`.